# ASP.NET WebApi HelpPage how to avoid showing multiple routes to same resource

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-routing

My question is somehow similar to [this question]:[WebApi help and multipe routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19836991/webapi-help-and-multipe-routes)

I have some custom routes defines like this one

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "NewsTopHeaders",
      routeTemplate: "api/news/headers/top",
      defaults: new { controller = "News", action = "GetTopHeaders" }
    );
```

and of course the default route (to cover everything that does not need custom routes)

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}",
            defaults: new {}
            );
```

Is there a possibility to exclude some of the actions from the default routes - so that no double url would point to the same resource?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code for multiple routing

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{        
    [Route("customers/{id}")]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    [Route("product/{id}")]
    public string Getv(int id)
    {
        return "product";
    }
}
```

Create a class in App Start

```
public class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.EnsureInitialized();
    }
}
```

Add the below code in application start in global.asax

```
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunatly I can not use attribute based routing as I am stuck with .NET 4.0 (deployment contraints)

Answer (score 1):

Following is an example of how you can achieve this. Here I am creating a custom `ApiExplorer`(which HelpPage uses depends on) which checks for a given action and route and decides whether to show the action or not. Note that I am using data tokens to store the route name for me to easily check it later. I do this because in Web API given a route, you cannot get the name out of it, so we are sticking in some custom information into the datatokens dictionary here.

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IApiExplorer), new CustomApiExplorer(config));

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
        dataTokens: new { routeName = "DefaultApi" },
        constraints: null,
        handler:null
    );
```

---

```
public class CustomApiExplorer : ApiExplorer
{
    public CustomApiExplorer(HttpConfiguration config) : base(config) { }

    public override bool ShouldExploreAction(string actionVariableValue, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IHttpRoute route)
    {
        //get current route name
        string routeNameKey = "routeName";
        if(route.DataTokens.ContainsKey(routeNameKey))
        {
            string routeName = (string)route.DataTokens[routeNameKey];

            ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor descriptor = (ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor)actionDescriptor;

            if(routeName == "DefaultApi" 
                && descriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType == typeof(ValuesController)
                && descriptor.ActionName == "Something")
            {
                return false; //do not show this action for this particular route
            }
        }

        // for other actions let the default behavior take place
        return base.ShouldExploreAction(actionVariableValue, actionDescriptor, route);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Out of the box Web API doesn't provide any 'MapHttpRoute' extension which takes in the 'data tokens', so here
/// we are creating a new extension.
/// </summary>
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IHttpRoute MapHttpRoute(this HttpRouteCollection routes, string name, string routeTemplate, 
                                            object defaults, object constraints, object dataTokens, 
                                            HttpMessageHandler handler)
    {
        if (routes == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("routes");
        }

        HttpRouteValueDictionary defaultsDictionary = new HttpRouteValueDictionary(defaults);
        HttpRouteValueDictionary constraintsDictionary = new HttpRouteValueDictionary(constraints);
        HttpRouteValueDictionary dataTokensDictionary = new HttpRouteValueDictionary(dataTokens);
        IHttpRoute route = routes.CreateRoute(routeTemplate, defaultsDictionary, constraintsDictionary, dataTokensDictionary, handler: handler);
        routes.Add(name, route);
        return route;
    }
}
```